# According to the "DI Method" (Tabular Method) - isn't every integral a sum of the derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, summation, taylor-expansion

Many years ago I encountered this really amazing solving technique called the "DI Method for integration" which is also called the tabular method (If I am not mistaken). It lets us choose two functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and construct this table, for one which we take the derivative over and over (until we hit $0$ or until we hit the same integral we started with) and the second function we integrate (Which will be much easier as it is just one part of the whole function we want to compute the integral of) And then take the product of the diagonals, with an alternating sign.

It lets us solve integrals such as $$ \int xe^x  ~ dx,  ~~\int \sin (x) e^x ~ dx$$ Pretty quickly (This is just a variation of the [Integration By Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) condensed in a fine table)

So I thought about this method, and wondered what would happend if we have this amorphous integral:

$$ \int f(x) ~ dx$$
And choose $g(x) = f(x)$ and $h(x) = 1$. This would give of this table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline 
\text{Sign}& D & I \\ \hline 
\color{red}{+} & \color{red}{f(x)} & 1  \\ \hline 
\color{green}{-} & \color{green}{f'(x)} & \color{red}{x} \\ \hline 
\color{purple}{+} & \color{purple}{f''(x)} & \color{green}{\frac{x^2}{2}} \\ \hline 
\color{blue}{-} & \color{blue}{f^{(3)}(x)} & \color{purple}{\frac{x^3}{6}} \\ \hline 
\vdots & \vdots & \color{blue}{\vdots} \\ \hline 
\end{array}$$

So we basically have a nice pattern, we can describe the integral as an infinite sum of derivatives as so:

$$ \int f(x) ~ dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(x) \cdot (-1)^k \cdot \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

Where $f^{(k)}(x)$ is the $k$-th derivative ($f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$).
This seems like a Taylor Series of a function, but comparing for example this specific infinite sum for $\frac{e^x}{x}$ we get a totally different sum then its Taylor expansion. I am not going to lie, the Taylor expansion seems to give a better approximation, but they are not the same as far as I checked:

$$ \int \frac{e^x}{x} ~ dx = \text{Ei}(x) \approx  e^x \left ( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{6}{x^4} + \mathcal{O} \left ( \frac{1}{x^5} \right ) \right ) ~~~ \text{Taylor} $$

Our sum, is something else, starting like:

$$ e^x \left ( 1 - \frac{x-1}{2} + \frac{x^2 -2x+2}{6} + \dots \right ) ~~~ \text{Our sum}$$

Which is much different.

In addition, why can't we break our sum into two different sums, one for the derivatives and one for the rest, which would give us that every integral of a function is the infinite sum of the derivatives multiplied by this sum, which is evaluated to $1-e^{-x}$:

$$ \int f(x) ~ dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(x) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = (1-e^{-x}) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(x)$$

> Why is it that different? Have I made a mistake somewhere in this
> progress? Or my way of thinking is completely off? I would like to
> hear what you think about it.

Thank you!

Comment: Your last paragraph "In addition..." is incorrect: $\sum_n a_n b_n \ne (\sum_n a_n)(\sum_n b_n)$ for the same reason why $ac+bd \ne (a+b)(c+d)$.

Comment: @angryavian You are correct, that was a silly mistake by me, although that seemed pretty awesome that the integral is the sum of derivatives multiplied by this random function. :-)

Comment: Regarding your specific example with the Ei function, you should start working with definite integrals instead of indefinite integrals, otherwise writing $\int \frac{e^x}{x} \, dx = \text{Ei}(x)$ makes no sense ($x$ is a dummy variable on the left-hand side, while the right-hand side and Taylor series is a function of $x$). Likewise, you've only worked out the tabular method as an indefinite integral; you need to think about definite integrals if you want to compare to a concrete example like the Ei function.